# Running functions in sync in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I want to run func2 run only after func1 has finished.

```
{
func1();
func2();//
}
```

But when func1() starts, func2() does not wait for func1() to get finished. func2() run simultaneously with func1(), which causes run time error, because func2() need some input from func1().
I also tried using async module, but got no success.

Edit: I run the function check(), which call two functions prompt() and copyProject(). copyProject() should run only after prompt() function has finished, but it start executing simultaneously.

```
var check = function check (){
        async.series([
            function(callback){
                prompt();
                callback(null);
            },
            function(callback){
                copyProject();
                callback(null);
            }
        ]);
};

var prompt = function prompt(){
      var prompts = [{
      name: "projectName",
      message: "What is the name of your project?"
    },{
      name: "authorName",
      message: "What is your name?",
    }];
    inquirer.prompt(prompts, function( answers ) {
      for (var key in answers) {
        if (answers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log(key + " -> " + answers[key]);
          infoToRender[key] = answers[key]
        }
      }
});
};

var copyProject = function copyProject (){
 // code to copy some files from one location to another based on input from prompt function
};
```

Comment: If a function does something asynchronous, it does take a callback or return a promise. In your attempt at using `async`, you'll have to pass the `callback` to the asynchronous function, not call it immidiately. Please show us your actual code.

Comment: You should be able to achieve your goal with async.series. Could you elaborate on what you expected as a result from using async.series and why this was not successful for you?

Comment: `func1` must be asyc, and if so, it takes a function as an argument `func1(done)`. Call your `callback` from inside that `done`

Comment: @Macro My only requirement is that the copyProject() function get executed only after prompt() function has finished executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `prompt` is itself an asynchronous function: The call to `inquirer.prompts` causes the function to **wait** and this makes it asynchronous. Since your `prompt` function does not use a callback, the `async` module can not know when `prompt` has finished: In contrast, it runs `prompt` and this function immediately returns. Hence `async` right afterwards runs `copyProject`.

What you need to do to solve this issue is to introduce a callback function in `prompt` that `async` "waits" for. So basically something like this:

```
var prompt = function (callback) {
  // Do your stuff here...
  inquirer.prompt(prompts, function (answers) {
    // Your for loop here...
    callback(null);
  });
};
```

Then, within `async` you need to do:

```
async.series([
  function (callback) {
    prompt(callback);
  },
  function (callback) {
    copyProject();
    callback(null);
  }
]);
```

Then `copyProject` is only run when `prompt` has been completed. Please note that `async.series` will **not** wait for `copyProject` to finish, in case this is an asynchronous function, as again, it does not take a callback. So same pattern applies here.

Comment: BTW, is it possible to achieve that goal without using async module.

Comment: Yes: Instead of the callback, simply run `copyProject` in the callback of your `inquirer.prompt` function. That's it :-). To put it in other words: If you have asynchronous functions and you want them to run sequentially, nest them. If you want to run them in parallel put them next to each other, as you would do with synchronous ones.